# Is it possible to use an unique identifiers, requesting Salesforce API?

Tags: api, limits

We do Salesforce API requests in behalf of our clients. Our clients continue doing API requests independently from us.

We're looking for a way that our API calls doesn't count against the concurrent API call limits.

Comment: If you're talking about the Salesforce API call limit, there is no way to workaround it. It's in place to count how many time an org is being called and limit that to ensure every org on the server (many orgs on the same server) is not taking too much resource regarding the other orgs. From Salesforce point of view they don't care who is calling the org as long as someone is doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Every API call to salesforce will count towards your limit. You can consider upgrading to a higher-tier edition of salesforce or buying more licenses in order to increase your limit but there's always a limit.

You'll likely want to consider a different integration architecture altogether if you wish to reduce your calls somehow. Some ideas off the top of my head:

- [Composite resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm) reduces round trips by letting you combine several API calls into one.
- Offloading data to an external database that is populated via regularly-scheduled data exports from salesforce (see ETL tools).
- Implement some caching scheme on your app.